# ERD diagram examples needed

Tags: erd

I remembered that there is a website providing a lot of ER diagrams. It even categorises diagrams into subjects. But I can't remember the address. Anyone who know / just came across any site like this please post the link for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous sites, let's hope one of these is the one you are looking for:

- [Creately.com](http://creately.com/diagram-community/popular/t/erd)
- [Smartdraw](https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/examples/)
- [Conceptdraw](http://www.conceptdraw.com/How-To-Guide/erd-entity-relationship-diagram-examples)